# Firefox 38 and Selenium IDE download link ?

Tags: selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

Most of the users unable to find a compatible version of these two softwares. So I shared the resourceful answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here I mentioned the download link for the Mozilla Firefox 38 and Selenium IDE 2.9.1.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2BjFNY5fXWubDZ5NDg3R0RIbGs?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can still install Selenium IDE 2.9.1 with the latest Firefox ESR 52 (or Firefox 38), but you need to install it manually.

Download the xpi file from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/ with the link "Download Anyway". I don't know why this option is only available with a browser other than Firefox... Use Chrome, IE, Safari or what you want, but not Firefox) and install it from the add-on page `about:addons` (Install add-on from file... option).